# This C++ stack implementation doesn't produce any output

Tags: c++, data-structures, stack, implementation

```
void solve(int n, int a[]) {
  stack<int> s;
  s.push(a[0]);
  for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    if (a[i] < s.top()) {
      while (!s.empty()) {
        cout << s.top() << " ";
        s.pop();
      }
      cout << "\n";
    } else {
      s.push(a[i]);
      cout << "\n";
    }
  }
}
```

Here `n` is the size of array `a[]`.
It doesn't produce any output on console.

example input: `a[] = {3, 1, 2}`

example expected output:

```
3
2 1
```

Comment: [I got some output](https://wandbox.org/permlink/biMDqByi9SEsdLaU). What is your input? Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @MikeCAT a[] = {3,1,2} and it should print

Comment: @MikeCAT 3 (newLine) 2 1

Comment: When `a[i] < s.top()`, you empty the stack. On the next iteration, you access `s.top()` whereupon your program exhibits undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

- You accessed `s.top()` without checking if `s` is empty at `if (a[i] < s.top()) {` and it is causing Segmentation Fault.
- Extra newlines are printed at the latter `cout << "\n";`.
- Values that are smaller than previous values are dropped.
- Last chunk of input won't be printed.

Try this:

```
void solve(int n , int a[]){
    stack<int> s; 
    s.push(a[0]);  
    for(int i=1;i<n;i++){
        if(!s.empty() && a[i] < s.top()){
            while(!s.empty()){
                cout << s.top() <<" ";
                s.pop();
            }
            cout << "\n";
        }
        s.push(a[i]); 
    }
    while(!s.empty()){
        cout << s.top() <<" ";
        s.pop();
    }
    cout << "\n";
}
```

Or this:

```
void flush_stack(stack<int>& s) {
    while(!s.empty()){
        cout << s.top() <<" ";
        s.pop();
    }
    cout << "\n";
}

void solve(int n , int a[]){
    stack<int> s; 
    s.push(a[0]);  
    for(int i=1;i<n;i++){
        if(!s.empty() && a[i] < s.top()){
           flush_stack(s);
        }
        s.push(a[i]); 
    }
    flush_stack(s);
}
```